# MongoRepository Find List in Array

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've got a `document` that looks like this

```
@Document
public @Data class Note {

    @Id
    private String noteId;
    private String owner;
    @TextIndexed
    private String name;
    @TextIndexed
    private String text;
    private List<String> tags;
    private LocalDate date;
}
```

Also I'm using `spring data mongodb` to operate on `mongodb` datastore.
I've created interface

```
public interface NoteRepository extends MongoRepository<Note, String> {
    List<Note> findByTags(List<String> tags);
}
```

My stored object looks like this

```
[
    {
        "noteId": "594e4adc3bc5152218f933b4",
        "owner": "system",
        "name": "simple note",
        "text": "My text",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
        ],
        "date": [
            1992,
            12,
            15
        ]
    }
]
```

But unless I don't provide the list of tags like `tag1, tag2, tag3` to `findByTags` method it won't return any result. For example `tag1, tag2` returns nothing etc. etc.

How should I conduct the search over such tags? Use some `TextCriteria`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on what you want to provide.

If you just want a single value then MongoDB does not care if the data is in an array and will simply look for the match in all entries

```
public interface NoteRepository extends MongoRepository<Note, String> {
    List<Note> findByTags(String tags);
}
```

If you want a list of variable size for comparison of "any" that may match, then there is a [keyword used by spring-mongo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) that effects the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operation:

```
public interface NoteRepository extends MongoRepository<Note, String> {
    List<Note> findByTagsIn(List<String> tags);
}
```

So the first is for where you just want `"tag1"` to match the data. And the second would match a `List` like `"tag1", "tag2"`, or anything as long as 'at least one' was actually present in the array being searched.

Comment: But if I for example has a composite object `Tag` with `id` and `name`, how should conduct the search? Create method - `findByTagsNameIn`?

Comment: @user1432980 Different thing. You would likely use `@Query` or simply start using the other methods. MongoRepository is really just for general CRUD. Most importantly, that is not the question you asked. If you have a new question, then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)